# Tenerife South Airport to Teide

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, spain, canary-islands, tenerife

Tenerife South is the biggest airport in the Canary Islands, and Teide is them most popular tourist attraction, so it would be very useful if the internet had information to offer as to how to get between the two. But Wikitravel, Tripadvisor and Lonely Planet Online don't say anything, and neither do the blogs I've found.

Google Maps suggests Bus 111 and then Bus 342 (2 hours, 25 minutes), but for each day the only route it gives begins at 8:30am. I find it hard to believe there's only one bus going there per day. I'll be arriving at around 3pm at the airport, so I need a later bus or shuttle.

Answer (score 2):

There are two bus lines for Teide, [342](http://www.titsa.com/index.php?accion=linea&IdLinea=342) line and [348](http://www.titsa.com/index.php?accion=linea&IdLinea=348) but none of them are good for you. However, Titsa Buses are oriented to transportation, not tourism, so, Maybe the bus won't wait for you when you leave it. Some people use those lines for hiking through Las Cañadas or even to reach the peak. (Maybe this is what you want).

Other options are a taxi, which I think they are too expensive, and a touristic bus but I think they have a schedule, so maybe this one is not an option.

However, as additional information, the road to the Teide only reaches about 2400m but Teide is 3718m tall, so if you want to reach the peak you have to do hiking (about 4-5 hours, and pretty tought. Also you might need to get a permission) or you have to book a trip on [cable car](http://www.telefericoteide.com/) which costs about 23€ (It is worth it)